# Partial order relation aRb is true when b contains a, 001R0101 is true - why?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

*Note: I'm taking a course in Polish, where the word "ciąg" is used, which translates to "sequence", but may be translated as a "word" or a "string".*

We have a set of binary sequences: `A = { 0, 00, 01, 10, 11, 000, 001, 010, 100, 111, ... }`.

We define a partial order relation $R \subseteq A^2$ so that $aRb$ is true if, and only if, sequence $b$ contains subsequence $a$. Examples: $001R0101$ is true, $110R0101$ is false.

...but 0101 doesn't contain 001 "as is", but rather after "skipping" the first 1 from it. I thought that if if a sequence contains a subsequence, it must contain it "in one block, as is" - without manipulating $b$ in any way. Why is this true/allowed?

Comment: Is this partial order used for anything after this? As long as it obeys all the properties of a partial order, it's perfectly valid to define it that way. But unless it's just an example/exercise to get you used to definitions, there's usually a reason for doing things that way (mathematically, it is perfectly OK to "skip" terms in a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence). Apparently not, in a [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring)).

Comment: It is later used to draw a Hasse diagram (for another set of binary sequences). And it looks like you "hit the nail" - I thought skipping terms in subsequences is not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English math and computer science, there is a common notion of "subsequence" (*not* "substring") that does not have to be a contiguous block. Under this notion, if we have a string, say $a_1 a_2 a_3 \ldots a_n$, a subsequence is defined to be $a_{i_1} a_{i_2} a_{i_3} \ldots a_{i_k}$, where $1 \le i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_k \le n$.
I would suspect that this is the definition intended in the course you are taking, and its a perfectly reasonable and useful definition. For, under this definition, $001$ is absolutely a subsequence of $0101$.

Note that the word "substring" is usually reserved for contiguous blocks, where "subsequence" may not have to be contiguous. This usage agrees with Wikipedia, see [substring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substring) and [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence).

*Caveat:* Of course, this is only speculation. This question is technically impossible to answer, because it's a matter of the way your course defined things. If your course makes a mistake, then how are we to know? And if not, there is nothing to answer definitively, only speculation. So I would avoid asking this type of question on mathSE, i.e. a question that does not have a real answer.

Answer (score -1):

There must be a typo somewhere,
because it looks to me
that it should be false,
not true.

Comment: I was assured this is not a typo.

Comment: Then it depends on the difference between "substring" and "subsequence" as user 6005 has pointed out.